# How is it possible that a cyclic group like $\mathbb Z_{2p}$ is isomorphic to a non-cyclic group of order $2p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

We know that a non-cyclic group can not be isomorphic to a cyclic group. But in Gallian there is a theorem which states that all non-cyclic groups of order $2p$ (where $p$ is prime) are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{2p}$ or $D_p$.

Since $\mathbb Z_n$ is a cyclic group, how can it be isomorphic to a non-cyclic group?

Comment: You might be referring to this theorem: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_Order_2p. Either "non-cyclic" or "$\mathbb Z_{2p}$" should be omitted in the theorem you stated.

Comment: Logically $A \vee B$ and $\neg A$ are not contradictory sentences. It just means that $B$ is always valide.

Comment: @player3236 Okay, so that means, If G is cyclic of order 2p, it is isomorphic to Z2p. If G is non-cyclic of order 2p, it is isomorphic to Dp or any other non-cyclic group of order 2p. Right?

Comment: More specifically, the theorem shows that the *only* non-cyclic group of order $2p$ is $D_p$.

Comment: Got it, Thanks!

Comment: If indeed Gallian says that "all non-cyclic groups of order $2p$ (where $p$ is prime) are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{2p}$ or $D_p$" then he's logically correct, but that's a ridiculous way to put it. A better statement would be: "all non-cyclic groups of order $2p$ are isomorphic to $D_p$."

Comment: Gallian says that if G is a group of order 2p  (where p is prime > 2), then G is isomorphic to Z2p or Dp. Then it goes on to prove that all non-cyclic groups of order 2p are isomorphic to Dp. I got confused because I took the meaning of the word 'OR' in a different way.  Since A ∩ B is a subset of A U B, I'm not sure whether we can use the word 'OR' in between Z2p and Dp.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible. Let $f$ be a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to a group $G$. If it is an isomorphism then the image of the generator of $\mathbb{Z}_n$, for example, $f(1)$ is a generator of $G$ as well.